# jquery datatable: get entire column value by button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I bind my json data using jquery datatable and add button on row.  Now how can I get a specific column data on list by button click? I can get a row value but can not find a way to get a column value.

Here is my Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "SympsService.asmx/GetSymptoms",
    method: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ organ_name: "toes" }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        var sympList = 'GetSymptoms' ? JSON.parse(data.d) : data.d;
        createDataTable('#symptomsTable', sympList);

        function createDataTable(target, data) {
            $(target).DataTable({
                destroy: true,
                paging: false, searching: false, info: false, data: data,
                columnDefs: [{
                    targets: [-1], render: function () {
                        return "<button type='button'>" + ('Choose') + "</button>"
                    }
                }],
                columns: [{
                        'data': 'Sympt',
                        'title': 'toes Symptoms',},
                {'data': null, 'title': 'Action' }]
               });
        }
        $('#symptomsTable').on("click", "tbody button", function () {
            var id = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(1)").data();
            //here i get every row data by button click
            //but i want specific column data on list
        }) 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use the Datatable inbuilt function [DataTables Column Data](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns()) column().data()

Answer (score 0):

try this, may help you.

```
$('#table tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
   var index = $(this).index();
   var column = $('#table').column(index);
});
```

Comment: when use console.log('column') it shows uncaught type error .column is not a function.
@saf21